# Failed to open the system default web browser. Is one installed? Pgadmin4

Tags: php, pgadmin-4

Just wondering has anyone come across this issue with pgadmin4?
Every time I go to open it, I get the following: 
Failed to open the system default web browser. Is one installed?.

Thanks

Comment: I changed the default browser like 5 times. It later worked with chrome, I didn't delete or run any special code

Answer (score 8):

In mac make sure the default browser is selected from System preference

Choose System Preferences from the Apple () menu.
Click General
Choose your web browser from the ”Default web browser”

If default browser is set, try to change it and try again. This should solve the problem.

Comment: This worked for me. Simply changing the default browser from Chrome to Safari and then back to Chrome resolved the issue.

Answer (score 7):

My pgAdmin4 was working fine until today, and then I also received the following:

> Failed to open the system default web browser. Is one installed?.

I updated to the most current version and still I received the error.

I did two other things before I fixed the problem so I'm not sure which solved it:

1. I remembered I got a strange pop up in my browser the day before. I ran a virus scan and a tracking cookie was found, I deleted it.
2. I changed my default browser from Edge to IE (in Windows 10) and then pgAdmin opened. I then put my default browser back to Edge.

Comment: changing default browser from Chromium to Edge solved my problem, many thanks

Comment: I could sorted as well with the browser change and back

Answer (score 4):

I've killed pgAdmin, then removed `.pgadmin` folder from the home directory, and now it works like a charm :)

Answer (score 4):

When running pgAdmin, wait for maybe 1-2 mins. It should automatically open in your browser. If you click the button to create a new pgAdmin window before that, it will fail because pgAdmin 4 isn't running yet. The wrong error message will be shown.

Comment: This is what worked for me! I was just too impatient, but when I waited, it opened automatically.

Answer (score 3):

If changing the default browser to IE/chromium/chrome does not work, you can try running it as an administrator. That always works for me

Answer (score 1):

The reason why most major browsers don't open up pgAdmin is that it is an applet and major browsers have dropped support for Java. Internet Explorer still supports Java applets at the time of this answer and thus works with IE.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you have some other app listening on port 5432 or some other is already running on this port and pgadmin not being able to override it.
You can check if there are any other apps at this port (in local host at ip http://127.0.0.1) by running following command in powershell:

```
netstat -ano | findstr :5432
```

Possible fixes for this problem:

1. You can configure pgadmin to run at port other than 5432, by right clicking on pgadmin (elephant icon) in your notification shade and click on 'configure' and changing the port to something else, like 22 there.
2. Or, if you have already setup lots of applications to use postgresql on port 5432 and don't want to change the port, you can kill the application running on 5432 by running:

```
taskkill /PID 5280 /F
```

Replace "5280" with the number listed next to LISTENING when you run the first command. this will kill what was running at 5432. Now, you can should be able to run pgadmin without any problems.

Here you can see me finding the app, killing it, checking if it's running after having killed and then checking after running pgadmin:
[image]

In first command, I have checked what's running at 5432 port.
In second command, you can see that I have killed it.
In third command, I have checked if there's anything running again.
Then I started pgadmin and checked what's running at port 5432 in fourth and fifth commands. (I clicked on pgadmin and then ran this command quickly, that's the reason you can't see 'LISTENING' in fourth command.)

Comment: Why is pgAdmin even conflicting with opening it's UI based on a port like this.  That's wack

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this problem and then 24 hours later everything seemed to be working fine again. I did not delete my internet history, restart my PC or change my default browser. The problem just seemed to fix itself. If you have tried some of the suggestions above and the problem still persists. Then maybe in 24 hours time you will just be lucky and see the problem unexpectedly go away.

Answer (score 0):

if you have this problem [Failed to open the system default web browser. Is one installed
]

I fixed that , just  by setting another default browser ,in my case I was using Chrome, then I installed Firefox Mozilla but for pgadmin4 to work, you must find the file pgadmin4, that is in  file programs :

```
postgresql/11/pgadmin4/bin/docs/en_US/html/
```

then you must replaced in the html file "browser" like default with another  browser that you prefer (besides Internet Explorer).

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that pgAdmin4 runs in an old version of Flask, the **two simplest options** are:

1. Install it thru **pip** (not pacman or apt-get) in a virtual env, here is the tutorial from pgAdmin [website](https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-python/)
2. Use a different program like [**Dbeaver**](https://dbeaver.io/download/)

Answer (score -1):

It happens because PGAdmin didn't found a default browser, note PGAdmin is web-based tool and it needs a browser to run.
On windows, go to system settings and set your preferred browser as default browser.